# How to convert UTC datetime to have T and Z in the output format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to convert UTC datetime value to have T and Z in the output format?

```
import datetime

strf_dttm = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print(type(strf_dttm), strf_dttm)
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'> 2020-11-04T12:13:35Z
```

Is this approach good or is there any other formatting option where I can pass the ISO standard and it will return me the appropriate date format?

Comment: You can define the desired format yourself with `strftime`, but not by just stringifying the object…!?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever `str` does is to show the date in a string representation. And `strftime` method is used to show the date in a specific format in string representation. If you don't need specific format, then `str()` is the pythonic way, otherwise use `strftime`